# What is the meaning of the "essentially the same" in this question?

Tags: linear-algebra

Although I have seen a couple of explanations about the phrase essentially the same it hasn't made any sense and I could not understand what I should do to prove the following claim: Let $S=\left\{ 1,2,\cdots,p  \right\}$ for some $p\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{s}$ is essentially the same as the space $\mathbb{R}^{p}$.

Answer (score 4):

It means that there is an isomorphism between them. Since these are vector spaces, isomorphisms are bijective linear maps. So the question could be rephrased into "Show that there exists a (i.e. at least one) linear map from $\Bbb R^p$ to $\Bbb R^S$ that is bijective."

The phrase 'essentially the same' hints to the fact that as mathematical objects, $\Bbb R^p$ and $\Bbb R^S$ are indistinguishable in terms of properties, e.g. dimension, scalar multiplication, vector addition and anything else imaginable. Even though they're constructed in different ways (one as a space of functions from $S$ into $\Bbb R$, the other as $p$-tuples of real numbers, both with vector structure inherited from $\Bbb R$), in every relevant and / or interesting respect they are the same space.

Answer (score 2):

It means that there is a *canonical* isomorphism between them (i.e. one you cannot fail to find once you start looking for one).
Note that this is more than just an isomorphism. The vector space of diffeentiable functions $f\colon ]17,42[\to \mathbb R$ with $f''+f=0$ is twodimensional, hence is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$, but is not canonically so. You *can* choose $\sin$ and $\cos$ as a *nice and pretty* basis, but that choice is not canonical.
On the other hand, your $\mathbb R^S$ is the set of fucntions $\{1,\ldots,p\}\to\mathbb R$ and allows a canonical identification with $\mathbb R^p$, the set of $p$-tuples of real numbers.